# Java. String cannot be converted to Object[]

Tags: java, casting

how can I resolve the issue?
I am reading the data from Excel file and the output is in String.
The method "getData" with DataProvider requires Object[][] return type.

```
public class Utilities extends Page {

    @DataProvider(name = "readProductNumber")
    public Object[] getData(Method method) {

        ReadDataFromExcel readDataFromExcel = new ReadDataFromExcel();
        String data = readDataFromExcel.ReadCellData(1, 0);


        return data;

    }
}
```

Error:(17, 16) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[]

Comment: Please follow the guidelines for asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Looks like you have put Zero effort to identify the problem yourself.

Comment: Nishit, I tried to resolve that myself, however with no success, that's why I wrote the question. I think this website is meant for that.

Comment: Yes, the website is meant for that, but we expect to know from you what all you tried. Especially, in this case, the error you mentioned explains clearly what the problem is. 
While we are here to help you, we can't do your job for you. We expect to see the effort that you have put in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` is an `Object`, but your method needs to return an `Object` array.

You could put it into an array like so: `return new Object[]{data}`